# Why are most mutations recessive?

Tags: genetics, molecular-biology, molecular-genetics, gene-expression, mutations

Why are most of deleterious mutations recessive in nature? I understood that if it's recessive then one reason may be that the mutant gene doesn't code for a functional protein and so there is no  phenotype to express.  But why is it recessive in the first place?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a bit ironic that you phrase your question with 'in the first place'. There is a parsimonious explanation for the effect: **Dominant deleterious variants are quickly removed by [purifying selection](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_selection_(natural_selection))** whereas recessive deleterious variants can "hide" in individuals that carry a dominant neutral/advantageous variant.

You can think about it this way: In heterozygous carriers (in which the other variant has a neutral or positive fitness effect), a recessive deleterious variant has no (strong, depending on the [dominance](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominance_(genetics)) coefficient) negative effect on fitness and therefore, in those heterozygotes, **purifying selection will not remove the variant (efficiently, again depending on the degree of dominance)** - it can only act on homozygous carriers of the recessive variant. A consequence of that is that the [**recessive deleterious allele usually segregates at low frequency with most carriers being heterozygous**](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominance_(genetics)#Addressing_common_misconceptions).

In short: This probably has little to do with there being more recessive deleterious variants *per se* (even though that might also be the case due to the mechanisms you described in your question). In the snapshot we are looking at when we investigate genetic data, the **likelihood of finding dominant deleterious alleles is way lower than finding recessive deleterious alleles as the latter usually just persist for a way longer period of time**.

Comment: @JewelJohnson: You are welcome. If the post answers your question, I'd be glad if you'd accept it. ;) Cheers!

Comment: How do I accept it?